# How do I put a redirect link into this button html code?

Tags: php, html, redirect, hyperlink

I'm not sure how to make this redirect this to another website, I also have a php file

```
                  <form id="frmLogin" action=login.php?login.php?"login.php?&quot;Login.aspx?nexonTheme=maplestory&quot;" method="post" name="frmLogin">
        <input type="hidden" value="/wEPDwUKMTY2MTY3MjU1M2Rk" id="__VIEWSTATE" name="__VIEWSTATE" />  <label class="passport_id">Nexon Passport ID</label><input type="text" size="16" tabindex="1" id="txtId" name="txtId" /> <label class="passport_pw">Nexon Passport P/W</label><input type="password" maxlength="12" tabindex="2" id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword" />&nbsp; <strong><font color="#ffffff"><label class="Maplestory PIC">Maplestory PIC</label></font></strong><input type="Maplestory PIC" maxlength="12" tabindex="2" id="txtMaplestory PIC" name="txtMaplestory PIC" /> <input type="submit" class="btn_signin" tabindex="3" id="btnLogin" value="" name="btnLogin" />
```

Comment: Your action "login.php?login.php?"login.php?&quot;Login.aspx?nexonTheme=maplestory&quot;" is not close to be compliant, to post to external website you need a complete URL.

Comment: checkout header(); to send a raw header to the browser. That should work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Sorry but from your code it looks like you're tying to make a phishing site of maple story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn_signin" tabindex="3" id="btnLogin" value="" name="btnLogin" onsubmit="window.location = 'targetPage.html';"/>
```